# Is it possible to sort in python 3 using buffer-like (pointer-based) string comparisons?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the problem of sorting all the suffixes of a string, where a suffix is the substring from some index i to the end of the string. Instead of creating a list of the sorted suffixes, we can create a list of the indices corresponding to the starting points of the sorted suffixes. Then we can do something like this:

```
text = ... some text string ...
sortedIndices = sorted([i for i in range(len(text))], 
                       key = lambda i: text[i:])
```

This works for short strings, but if the string is sufficiently long, we'll run out of memory because the key function results in a copy of the suffix, and all the keys are generated at the outset. In python 2.7 there's a slick way around this, namely, the buffer() function:

```
sortedIndices = sorted([i for i in range(len(text))], 
                       key = lambda i: buffer(text, i))
```

In this case, the key is just a pointer into the text string, so the total memory needed is much less (O(n) vs O(n*n)). Hence, it will work with much longer strings. This works beautifully in 2.7, but in 3.x the buffer() function has been removed in favor of memoryview, which unlike buffer doesn't -- AFAIK -- support pointer-based string comparisons (i.e., without using the tobytes method, which creates a copy of the string). My question is: Is there any way to do something similar in python 3.x?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like memoryview doesn't do that.  That might actually be a good thing.

You can still do this with a class, which is more object oriented anyway:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import sys
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class Suffix_comparison:
    def __init__(self, string, starting_position):
        self.string = string
        self.starting_position = starting_position

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.string[self.starting_position:] < other.string[other.starting_position]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.string[self.starting_position:] == other.string[other.starting_position]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.string

    __repr__ = __str__

def main():
    list_ = []
    for line in sys.stdin:
        stripped_line = line.rstrip('\n')
        list_.append(Suffix_comparison(stripped_line, 5))

    list_.sort()

    for line in list_:
        print(line)

main()
```

Comment: You seem to be solving a different problem than the one I posed. You're sorting fixed-length suffixes from a set of input strings. The problem I'm interested in is sorting the set of all suffixes (ranging from length 1 to length n) of a single n-character input string. Also, you're storing all the class instances (each of which includes the string) in the list, so you would run into the same memory issue.

Comment: Only considering `Suffix_comparison`, there is a bug in the `__lt__` and `__eq__` functions. It can be fixed by comparing to `other.string[other.starting_position:]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've been working on this problem too.

And I've just shifted from Python 2.7 to 3.  WinPython, which has a very cool editor called Spyder by the way.

As far as I can tell, memoryview objects are totally useless.

I also tried the itertools.islice function, but couldn't see how to get that going either.

So decided to write my own little comparison function:

def suffixArrayCompare(x, y):
     global globalText

```
 i = 0
 end = len(globalText) - max(x, y)
 while i < end:
     if globalText[x+i] < globalText[y+i]:
         return -1
     elif globalText[x+i] > globalText[y+i]:
         return 1

     i += 1

 return 0
```

And it's called like this:

```
indexes = sorted(indexes, key = functools.cmp_to_key(lambda x,y:suffixArrayCompare(x, y)))
```

This is as fast as I can make this run.  It's still not as fast as the buffer way in 2.7, but not too far off.  And it doesn't copy anything.

This

```
#indexes = sorted(indexes, key = lambda x: globalText[x:])
```

runs nearly as fast, but has the memory problems you mention.